# Sort data by date in WordPress by using get_post_meta()

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to sort all the data in the table of WordPress, with the function get_post_meta() ? or may be I need to implement another function or algorithm.
Here's the code

```
$data = get_post_meta(parameter a, parameter b);
   echo '<table id="mi-careerform-table" cellspacing="0" class="widefat fixed" style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: -1px;">';
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<th width="15%">Name</th>';
   echo '<th width="10%">Company</th>';
   echo '<th width="15%">Email</th>';
   echo '<th width="15%">Phone</th>';
   echo '<th width="55%">Message</th>';
   echo '</tr>';

foreach($data as $item){
    $field = json_decode($item);
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>'.$field->name.'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$field->company.'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$field->email.'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$field->phone.'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$field->message.'</td>';
       echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: no you cant sort it with using `get_post_meta()` you may need to write query for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want to do with your code but in WordPress there is a class `wp_query`. You can pass arguments and order your posts or your  custom codes by date.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

See here for more info [WP_QUERY](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).